# Not finding .NET 3.5 SP1 in the Roles menu

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5

When I download the .NET 3.5 SP1 exe and run it, it unpacks and I get a message saying that

```
"Use the Roles Manager to configure .NET 3.5 SP1"
```

When I go to the Role Manager, I do not see the .NET 3.5 SP1 listed. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Server is the entry you want to tick(le)...

Comment: How do I check in SP1 is installed? I checked Application Server and installed the .NET 3.5.1 but some features that are available in SP1 are not enabled in my application

Comment: 3.5.1 is 3.5 SP1 - at least that's how I've always read that version string ;)  Also see this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198931

Answer (score 3):

You can install this directly without choosing application server under roles by going directly to "Features". There you choose to specifically install the .NET Framework with or without the WCF Activation piece.